Grid mapping not correctly working
I am working with ros2 foxy,raspberry, and rplidar to build 2D grid map for a mobile robot. I am using ros2 slamtoolbox with following command ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py params_file:=/home/pi/ros2_foxy_ws/src/articubot_one/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml use_sim_time:=false  Initially, the map is fine  as I drive the robot to build the environment map the map get crazy



Seems like there might be an issue in the way your tf tree is being published, likely in the  odom->base_link transform (Probably not being published or a static transform is published). You can refer to REP105 (https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) to setup your coordinate frames correctly. Could you share how the tf tree is setup and how the odom->base_link transform is generated?
